# Flutter Auth (BLoC pattern & rxDart)?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I display the error message on the login page ???

This is the Bloc that I made :
bloc :

```
class LoginBloc extends Object with Validators{
  final _repository = EresidenceRepository();
  final _userid = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _password = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _imei = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final _coordinate = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  final BehaviorSubject<ApiResponse<login_responses>> _subject = BehaviorSubject<ApiResponse<login_responses>>();

  Function(String) get userid => _userid.sink.add;
  Function(String) get password => _password.sink.add;
  Function(String) get imei => _imei.sink.add;
  Function(String) get coordinate => _coordinate.sink.add;

  Stream<String> get useridValidation => _userid.stream.transform(useridValidator);
  Stream<String> get passwordValidation => _password.stream.transform(passwordValidator);
  Stream<bool> get submitCheck => Rx.combineLatest2(useridValidation, passwordValidation, (e,p) => true);

  login() async {
    try {
      login_responses response = await _repository.login(
          _userid.value, _password.value, _imei.value, _coordinate.value);
      _subject.sink.add(ApiResponse.completed(response));

      prefsBloc.changePrefsLogin(
          PrefsState(false, response.data.userid, response.data.password, _imei.value, _coordinate.value)
      );

      print(_imei.value + " " + _coordinate.value);
      print(response);

    } catch (e) {
      _subject.sink.add(ApiResponse.error(e.toString()));
      print(e);
      print(_userid.value);
    }
  }

  dispose(){
    _userid.close();
    _password.close();
    _imei.close();
    _coordinate.close();
    _subject.close();
  }

  BehaviorSubject<ApiResponse<login_responses>> get subject => _subject;

}

final login = LoginBloc();
```

I have tried methods like my UI code, but an error message appears on a dark background. I tried to display an error message during ERROR status. I want to display an error message on the login page / login form. how did you do that ???

hope anyone can help me

ui :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: StreamBuilder<ApiResponse<login_responses>>(
          stream: login.subject,
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              switch (snapshot.data.status) {
                case Status.LOADING:
                  break;
                case Status.COMPLETED:
                  login_responses result = snapshot.data.data;
                  print(result.data.password + " " +result.data.userid);
                  AppRoutes.push(context, OtpLoginPage());
                  break;
                case Status.ERROR:
                  return CupertinoAlertDialog(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data.message),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      CupertinoDialogAction(
                        child: Text('OK'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                  break;
              }
            }
            print("FORM LOGIN");
            return _formLogin();
          }
      ),
    );
  }
_formLogin() {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
      child: Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: SizeConfig.widthMultiplier * 1, vertical: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 1),
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          imageUrl: "",
                          placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.broken_image),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 2),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                child: StreamBuilder<String>(
                                  stream: login.useridValidation,
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) => DataTextField(
                                    errorText: snapshot.error,
                                    hintText: "No Handphone",
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                    icon: Icons.phone,
                                    onSubmitted: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(passwordFocusNode),
                                    onChanged: login.userid,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true),
                                  ),
                                )
                            ),
                            Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 2),
                                child: StreamBuilder<String>(
                                  stream: login.passwordValidation,
                                  builder: (context, snapshot) => PasswordTextField(
                                  errorText: snapshot.error,
                                    hintText: "Password",
                                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                                    onSubmitted: () {
                                      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                                    },
                                    onChanged: login.password,
                                    focusNode: passwordFocusNode,
                                  ),
                                )
                            ),
                            Container(
                                width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 2.5),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () => AppRoutes.push(context, ForgotPasswordPage()),
                                  child: Text(
                                    Strings.titleForgotPass+" ?",
                                    style: AppTheme.styleSubTitlePurpel,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                  ),
                                )
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 5),
                              child: StreamBuilder<bool>(
                                stream: login.submitCheck,
                                builder: (context, snapshot) => AppButton(
                                    onPressed: snapshot.hasData ? () => login.login(context) : null,
                                    text: Strings.signin
                                ),
                              )
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                    )
                ),
                Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 2.5),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              Strings.dontAccount,
                              style: AppTheme.styleSubTitleBlackSmall,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            ),
                            Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: SizeConfig.widthMultiplier * 1),
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () => AppRoutes.push(context, RegistrationPage()),
                                  child: Text(
                                    Strings.registration,
                                    style: AppTheme.styleSubTitlePurpel,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                  ),
                                )
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                    )
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you don't have any material "background" for your error dialog. Try to wrap your StreamBuilder with Scaffold or Material widget. And for setting your errors for your Textfields you already have corresponding errorStreams